# Hiding Fields in subtasks which are active/set in parent task in Odoo 15 Enterprise

Tags: odoo, odoo-15, odoo-enterprise

Working on Odoo 15 enterprise

I am trying to hide some fields in Subtasks which are active in Parent task

ex: if Field A is set/active in parent task, I want to hide that Field A in subtask,

bec it is not required to fill same field again in subtasks,

Please, Help me to achieve this

Thank You

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I applied condition parent task is set on subtasks through studio, but it didnt work,